# Why Akka HTTP close user connection, when multiple messages is produced?

Tags: scala, websocket, connection, akka, akka-http

I have a simple WebSocket application, which is based on `Akka HTTP`/`Reactive streams`, like this https://github.com/calvinlfer/akka-http-streaming-response-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/experiments/calvin/ws/WebSocketRoutes.scala#L82.

In other words, I have `Sink`, `Source` (which is produced from `Publisher`), and the Flow:

```
Flow.fromSinkAndSource(incomingMessages, outgoingMessages)
```

When I produce more, than 30 messages per second to the client, `Akka` closes a connection.

I cannot understand, where is a setting, which configure this behaviour. I know about [OverflowStrategy](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/OverflowStrategy.html), but I don't explicitly configure it.

It seems, that I have `OverflowStrategy.fail()`, or my problem looks like it.

Comment: and what does your `outgoingMessages` look like? The one from the code linked clearly has the overflow strategy set to fail...

Comment: @FredericA. my `outgoingMessages` is `Source.fromPublisher(publisher).watchTermination() { (_, future: Future[Done]) =>`

Comment: @FredericA. https://pastebin.com/vU7A01G8 is my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tune [Internal buffers](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-rate.html#internal-buffers-and-their-effect).

There are two ways, how to do it:

1) **application.conf**:

```
akka.stream.materializer.max-input-buffer-size = 1024
```

2) You can configure it explicitly for your Flow:

```
Flow.fromSinkAndSource(incomingMessages, outgoingMessages)
  .addAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(initial = 1, max = 1024))
```